# Appropriateness of Tweedie GLM for modeling average daily driving distance with unknown numerator and denominator

Tags: generalized-linear-model, modeling, poisson-distribution, gamma-distribution, tweedie-distribution

I have a dataset of cars and want to model a variable called average daily driving distance. The variable was calculated before I received the dataset as:

*average daily driving distance = total driving distance in the days between last two inspections / days between last two inspections.*

However, I only have access to the quotient and do not know the total driving distance nor the number of days between inspections for each car.

If I were modeling the total driving distance for each car during a certain period, a Tweedie GLM with a Tweedie index parameter between 1 and 2 could be appropriate, as the data is positively continuous with exact zeros. The number of times a car is driven in a certain period could be described as the outcome of a Poisson process, and the distances of each ride could be seen as gamma-distributed (although not entirely accurately since there is plausibly some dependence between car rides - ie. going to work and back home, but perhaps these could be seen as one event).

Since the quotient data is also positively continuous with exact zeros, I am wondering if it would be legitimate to fit a Tweedie GLM to model the average daily driving distance. However, I am struggling with the interpretation of the model in Poisson and Gamma terms.
Can a Tweedie GLM still be used in this case?

Comment: I've seen the Tweedie distribution applied in similar cases for rainfall distribution where it is a positive number with zero values also.  I can't see how that's any different to the case of modeling distance traveled.   It would depend on the case where driving or no driving is performed.